# lisp scheme list

Tags: list, lisp, scheme

Why the result of `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` is `((1 2) 3 4)`?

I wonder why the result length is 3(3 elements). My intuition makes me think that
`(list 1 2)` is a list, `(list 3 4)` is also a list. By using `cons` procedure, result should be two elements with each element a list, but the result is not as I expect.

Can anybody tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: `cons` takes a value and a list and prepends the value to the list.  How is the result unexpected?

Comment: My intuition make me think the result may be ((1 2) (3 4))

Answer (score 7):

`(list a b c)` is equivalent to `(cons a (list b c))` by definition (or, if you continue the transformation, `(cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))`.

So if you write `(cons 1 (list 3 4))`, this is equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))`, or to `(list 1 3 4)`.

Now, replace `1` with `(list 1 2)`, and you get this: `(cons (list 1 2) (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))`, or equivalently `(list (list 1 2) 3 4)` (or, fully written out, `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 nil)) (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))`).

The key here is that `cons` is not `append`, nor `list` (which treat all their elements equally): it is inherently asymetrical, when dealing with lists. The left spot holds the element ("head"); the right one holds the rest of the list ("tail").